# Null variable = "" evaluates to Null?

Tags: vb6

I have a variable equal to Null, but if I ask whether it is equal to "" it evaluates to Null?  Why wouldn't it be false?

```
var1 = vbNull
Debug.Print var1 = ""
```

The output is `Null`.  Why wouldn't it be `false`?

Comment: I've forgotten VB, but in many languages a single '=' is an assigment while '==' is an equality check. also, watch the "smart quotes".

Comment: "Why" isn't really a valid question.  The only answer is "Because that is how = was implemented."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB6 has [null propagation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez6365dt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). The result of any expression involving `Null` is always null.

```
' in this code below V always has the value Null
Dim V As Variant
V = 1 + Null
V = Null + Right$("SomeText", 1)
V = Right("SomeText", 0)
```

Comment: @CraigJ - As the article link indicates, Null propagation is commonly used in database applications. VB6 evolved from VBA (Visual Basic for Applications), and VBA was developed with the needs of Microsoft Office automation in mind, which includes Access database apps. It seemed like a good idea at the time :)

Comment: Wikipedia indicates that Visual Basic began as a GUI interface module (code named "Ruby") that was combined with the "Embedded BASIC engine designed for Microsoft's abandoned 'Omega' database system." So it seems VB was designed for DB apps from the start.

Comment: @rskar I don't think VB6 evolved from VBA.  It was probably the other way round.

Comment: @CJ7 You're technically correct, since VB 1.0 was its own thing. But it seems we have Joel Spolsky to thank for much of the direction taken (http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html); he wanted a VB for Excel with `Variant`, `For Each`, and `With`. VBA came out same time as VB 3.0; VB 2.0 introduced `Variant` (http://bc-programming.com/blogs/2013/05/history-of-development-visual-basic-2-0/).